# How to add extends type guards to conditional types? Or equivalent

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types, typeguards

Let's say I have a class with a generic parameter. It has conditional types on some of the class' properties. These conditional types depend on the generic parameter being one of the two possible enum values. In the constructor I pass a type that follows the same type bounds as the generic parameter. What I expect is the check `login_type === TwoChoices.REGISTER` to narrow down the type of the class' generic parameter `T`, however this does not happen. Here's the example.

```js
enum TwoChoices {
    LOGIN,
    REGISTER
}

class ConditionalGenericClass<T extends TwoChoices> {
    password: string;
    email: string;
    username?: T extends TwoChoices.REGISTER ? string : never;
    constructor(login_type: T) {
        this.password = '';
        this.email = '';
        if (login_type === TwoChoices.REGISTER) {
            this.username = '';
        }
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAKg7gewMIAsEEsDGwDOUDeAUFCVADIDyA4gJIByANMaQEoCitAyjGy4QL6FCmADYBDHHiQIQAE3QAXdDLEiqoYACcsScZIA8MKMAAeC0LLzxkaLLgB8BZiQAOEnIk2yAXFBwLtEABzAG5nYwgxdBFff0DQ8LAcLRAxCGAAfl8jU3M5K0RUDGwcADp2Lh4WKAy-APRgqF8QYAA3LTDSKEwZOLBMBQRNAAoRBCCGgH0FAE8XYGyASicuroUUdDK3SU9ZKABeKAByI87VknXN0uBI6IPj0-Cu9AAzKFHxqdn5g-3D6yKdjKFRo3F4yyI53OlzKSRSaWA9xOZ3Ogi6gn4QA)

The above throws a `TypeError`: `Type '""' is not assignable to type '(T extends TwoChoices.REGISTER ? string : never) | undefined'.`.

What I would expect to be able to write is just add a type guard with a `C extends TwoChoices.REGISTER` as the function return type like this:

```js
enum TwoChoices {
    LOGIN,
    REGISTER
}

function typeGuardExtendsTwoChoicesRegister<C extends TwoChoices>
    (login_type: C): C extends TwoChoices.REGISTER 
{
    return login_type === TwoChoices.REGISTER;
}

class ConditionalGenericClass<T extends TwoChoices> {
    password: string;
    email: string;
    username?: T extends TwoChoices.REGISTER ? string : never;
    constructor(login_type: T) {
        this.password = '';
        this.email = '';
        if (typeGuardExtendsTwoChoicesRegister(login_type)) {
            this.username = '';
        }
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAKg7gewMIAsEEsDGwDOUDeAUFCVADIDyA4gJIByANMaQEoCitAyjGy4QL6FCAMzAhMAF3QIQUCQE8ADsCpgAhgCcAJmwAeE0FpzxkaLLhbAA5uhwGNAHiRRg+w3hOoM2HAD5mJAAUADYINiAA+grKAFxQSACUcc6uBiBGsIhe5jgAdOxcPCxQhESkUBrAEmAasqHhUUrAUAC8bZmm3rj5HDTcvADcAkKYwWo4eEgyWuhSMmrBVKDAGlhIYxMOMC5u6R5ZZj6+BAFQiuM4iNpxdqsgVkPlwBBq6ME3EncPp2A4KyBqCDAAD8cW2qXcHWyPh6hV4UGBUFu6HuUDiIGAADcVo9SJgZLcwJIEBoQmEUY1YrAEidyuUJChbLlzhMrlpWlAAOSc3F0uSMvLPV7BDnc3l09DCKCBaIqdTaPRpIyeQ4Way2exkhqyhI0sp8ukMpm-f6A5otLk807lQQ2gRAA)

However it seems like `X extends Y` is not a valid type guard return type.

What is the correct, better way to statically type these kinds of JavaScript's dynamic type scenarios?

You're probably going to suggest using class inheritance like this:

```js
class LoginCredentials {
    password: string;
    email: string;
    constructor() {
        this.password = '';
        this.email = '';
    }
}

class RegisterCredentials extends LoginCredentials {
    username: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.username = '';
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=0&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyD2BzAlgOwMICcCmATbqALsmCDAN4BQ0N0ADpBAO7ya4Bc0EhmaiA3NVrYAtmGQhO3XqgFCaweKmkBXYIVYAKAJTQqtA9EIALZBAB0DKCzbQAvNADkjwYdomz50eJD2nL+WgAX0oQylBGaAAlbBRubEwsPAJiUhhsAA9CAlwYBBQMHHwiEjI9QJUIBNQwEWwpHj5XWkVlHjUNTB1ytxoIFToEnWa3DwtK6trsP2cR4NCgA)

But in my view having to change the way I code just to encode types doesn't seem to correspond with my understanding of TypeScript's philosophy of being merely JavaScript's superset to which you just add some typing information, but instead it requires you to change the way you code JavaScript. Using classes also doubles the line count when transpiling to ≤`es5`, especially so when using `const enum`s in the first code block when compared to class inheritance method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots going on here:

- you don't want to make `username` optional because it needs to be required when T is `TwoChoices.REGISTER`.
- the proper syntax for a type guard function is to use `is` to assert that the variable is of the checked type.  You don't use a generic here, as the return type uses the name of the variable rather than the type.

```
function isRegister(login_type: TwoChoices): login_type is TwoChoices.REGISTER {
    return login_type === TwoChoices.REGISTER;
}
```

- limiting T with `T extends TwoChoices` doesn't mean that T *can only be one* of the two choices.  These are both valid, as far as typescript is concerned:

```
const myClass = new ConditionalGenericClass<TwoChoices.LOGIN | TwoChoices.REGISTER>(TwoChoices.LOGIN);
const myClass = new ConditionalGenericClass<TwoChoices>(TwoChoices.LOGIN);
```

- checking the type of `login_type` in the constructor will narrow your understanding of the `login_type` variable, but it doesn't narrow the generic T of the class -- this is mainly because of the previous bullet point.  If T is `TwoChoices` and `login_type` is `TwoChoices.REGISTER`, then `username` is `never`, not `string` like you would expect, because it is based on T rather than `login_type`.
- you're right, I do think inheritance is better.

Possible Solution

Given the messiness of the current setup, I think you'll have to assert that you've got the right type for `username` with `as` since typescript won't be able to verify it on its own. This seems to work:

```
type ConditionalUsername<T> = T extends TwoChoices.REGISTER ? string : never;

class ConditionalGenericClass<T extends TwoChoices> {
    password: string;
    email: string;
    action: T;
    username: ConditionalUsername<T>;
    constructor(login_type: T) {
        this.password = '';
        this.email = '';
        this.action = login_type;
        this.username = ((isRegister(login_type)) ? '' : undefined) as ConditionalUsername<T>;
    }
}

const loginClass = new ConditionalGenericClass(TwoChoices.LOGIN);
// expect type to be never
const loginU = loginClass.username;

const registerClass = new ConditionalGenericClass(TwoChoices.REGISTER);
// expect type to be string
const registerU = registerClass.username;
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKg7gewMIAsEEsDGwDOUDeAUFCVADIDyA4gJIByANMaQEoCitAyjGy4QL6FCAMzAhMAF3QIQUdDhbAA5vInAATgAoANghUgA%20hICeAB2AAuWIlQZsOAJRXd%20o2eBy88ZGiy4AdOxcPCwEzCTqwBJg6rIu6IYm5lAAvGnWPnYBQTTcvADcAkJJHkgyACboUjIAhtoAqjgaIDUQwAA8MAB8qbBQwAAeaiDlXja%209oEcuSFQAPxQOBLqCUpQViDAAG4ahYSY2jU4eGUjVdIt2lSgGlhIh8ed-UOgoxm2fjg9RKRQpkc4RDqcpWJYrEBKQq-YAQGrobSg5arKGkGqSC5WGAokhgJqxVqWKCnSrVS6NZoEzpdbFQTAyMFgSQILTxRLuTEOMK-X4SFDyfz-Y5A8q9ADkoppPL5OH8MLh2jFEvC3N5-LRpN6rLc5klpFVMtxFLavU0mnkihUSw0Oj0CW1wAcnIW4vWUDE5WAwgSwHKnKORIq51qDTxLTaVJpgkE%203pEigrPuAN6mzgAbOpLq102K0wieOmm8H0mlFodAchQA9BXnuZJFASvWEFAAEYeTY7dQxkBLeO2kD1TV9vMG0MEvZ07txyKWtTqYfJ4Cp4lBy5Z265h44AvjLIynJ5FjlwhVmvAOsNiRN1uLJEQrs96eqDQDlJQR9Wueb-yG-FtQpAA)